# How to Caching Bitmaps in a ContentProvider?

Tags: android

How do you comprehend this note

> **Note**: A ContentProvider might be a more appropriate place to store
>   cached images if they are accessed more frequently, for example in an
>   image gallery application.

in this training article https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html? Since I can't get `Bitmap` or `File` from `Cursor`, how can I cache Bitmaps via ContentProvider?

Comment: check the sample code in the following link: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: @GMRamesh That is the exact same link the poster linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually **can** read and write Files using a ContentProvider.

To support this in your own ContentProvider you'll have to include your supported File MIME types in the *getStreamTypes()* method. Check the MIME types section of the Android [ContentProvider tutorial here for more info](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#FileMIMETypes).

You will also need to implement the *[openFile(Uri uri, String mode) method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#openFile%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29)* which is where you'll actually choose the File directory and name based on the Uri provided to the ContentResolver. Here's a sample implementation of that method:

```
  @Override
  public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
      File root = getContext().getFilesDir();
      File path = new File(root, uri.getEncodedPath());
      path.mkdirs();
      File file = new File(path, "file_"+uri.getLastPathSegment());

      int imode = 0;
      if (mode.contains("w")) {
        imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_WRITE_ONLY;
        if (!file.exists()) {
          try {
            file.createNewFile();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
      if (mode.contains("r"))
        imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY;
      if (mode.contains("+"))
        imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_APPEND;

      return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, imode);
  }
```

You can use whatever logic you'd like here to choose your File directory. This code just uses the applications files directory, but for the purposes of Bitmap caching this should probably use a temp cache directory.

Finally, your code to access the ContentProvider file data should look something like this:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
InputStream inputStream = cr.openInputStream(uri);
```

Alternatively you'd use *ContentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)* to write your file data to the ContentProvider.

The Bitmap caching tutorial would require a fair bit of modifications to use a ContentProvider as the Disk cache, but I do believe this is what that note was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using the `https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader` library for downloading and caching images

You can download the library as a JAR-file that is easily included into any Android project

Features from the official page:

->Multithread image loading

->Possibility of wide tuning ImageLoader's configuration (thread pool size, HTTP options, memory and disc cache, display image options, and others)

->Possibility of image caching in memory and/or on device's file sysytem (or SD card)

->Possibility to "listen" loading process

->Possibility to customize every display image call with separated options Widget support

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned passage emphasizes that instead of finding and processing all data just when it is requested, You better implement a separate content model (or use built in ones) which silently indexes data and also saves the previews (thumbnails of images, or first 2 lines of a text files  etc) on disk. This achieves:

1. Less RAM used, since pre-processed data is ready on disk. For example, a really long `List view` need not load all the previews as `Drawable`'s at once in memory. It might just ask for cached data from the content model/provider in small batches to the in-memory cache as it scrolls.
2. Save CPU. In-memory cache is volatile and needs recreation again, while on disk cache saves us from this extra processing.